# Exact string matching in r

Tags: regex, r, string-matching

I struggling with exact string matching in R. I need only exact match in sentece with searched string:

```
sentence2 <- "laptop is a great product"
words2 <- c("top","laptop")
```

I was trying something like this:

```
sub(paste(c("^",words2,"$")),"",sentence2)
```

and I need replace laptop by empty string only - for exact match (laptop) but didn't work...

Please, could you help me. Thanks in advance.

Desired output:

```
is a great product
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
gsub(paste0("^",words2," ",collapse="|"),"",sentence2)
#[1] "is a great product"
```

The result of `paste0("^",words2," ",collapse="|")` is `"^top |^laptop "` which means "either 'top' at the beginning of string followed by a space or 'laptop' at the beginning of string followed by a space".

Comment: You can also use `paste0("^",words2," ", collapse = "|")` instead of two times `paste`

Comment: @Floo0, yes indeed! Thanks, I'll edit my answer! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match entire words, then you can use `\\b` to match word boundaries.

```
gsub(paste0('\\b', words2, '\\b', collapse='|'), '', sentence2)

## [1] " is a great product"
```

Add optional whitespace to the pattern if you want to replace the adjacent spaces as well.

```
gsub(paste0('\\s*\\b', words2, '\\b\\s*', collapse='|'), '', sentence2)

## [1] "is a great product"
```